# How to get Salesforce Data in java

Tags: spring, salesforce, spring-social

I have username and password for salesforce. I tried using REST API way, it requires clientid, client secret and redirecturl. Client is not willing to share them. Is there any alternate to get the data by just using Username and password?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [username & password OAuth flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm).  Here is an example Java app that does that: https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-rest-starter

Answer (score 0):

Ask the client to create a public Rest Service as described here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008s2KIAQ
This way it does not require any authentication and anyone can access the service.